# Music is taking up all my iPhone 5 storage

Tags: music, storage

My storage is almost all used up and I cant update software or take pictures.  It looks like Music is taking up aLOT of space.  How can I make sure that if I delete off phone it doesn't delate on iTunes also?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting music off your phone doesnt affect the itunes library's contents (in  your case Music)

So you can *un-sync your music../ update your library..* and put whatever you want back on.